# Mod Rewrite - Rewrite URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've to change my URL from

`https://example.com/public/contact.php` (the real path)

to

`https://example.com/contact`

using mod-rewrite.

`contact` is just a placeholder, it should work with every file in the `public` directory. Like `/home` or `/login`

I was able to remove the file extionsion with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean to "change"? `/public/contact.php`is actually the real path to the file and you want it to be accessed through https://example.com/contact ?

Comment: yes @EduardoEscobar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^\./]+)/?$
RewriteRule .* /public/%1.php [L]
```

Note: This will not handle two or more level URLs, i.e:  `https://example.com/contact/form`

Comment: No, take a look to your apache server's error log and see what's the reason of the 404

Comment: Thanks it's working now! but i have another little problem.. when i visit `example.com` i would like to show the `index.php`.

Comment: These rules won't conflict neither with `https://example.com` nor `https://example.com/index.php`.

Comment: When i'm on `example.com` i get the `index of \` page.